# How To add Php code snippest at the begineing of a .php file using php

Tags: php

I have a .php file, say "index.php" . This file is being generated dynamically and I want to add the following code at the beginning of the file.

```
   <?php
        session_start();
    require_once('login/auth.php');
        require_once('config.php');
   ?>
```

Intention is to force user to sign up or sign in before they see this file. But I wasted a whole day and turned into nothing as resultant file is blank. what I found is , its facing problem with `<?php`  and `?>`

if I replace them with their equivalent entities `&lt;?php` and `?&gt;` then they gets added easily but its not what I wanted.

So , question is how to add this  original code to the beginning on file dynamically. Can someone help please?

Comment: This is most certainly now how PHP is meant to work. There's probably a better solution than code generation for whatever problem you're tackling.

Comment: If you can use `.htaccess to set PHP config options: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Comment: Those spaces will cause `session_start` to error out because headers are already sent.

Comment: @meagar Just to clarify: you meant 'not', not 'now'.

Comment: Yes. *Not* how PHP was meant to work :p

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$preamble = <<<EOL
<?php 
   session_start();
   yada;
   yada;
   yada;
?>
EOL;

file_put_contents('index.php', $preamble);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
<?php

  file_put_contents('index.php', "   <?php
        session_start();
    require_once('login/auth.php');
        require_once('config.php');
   ?>");
```

**Edit**: Marc's idea to use heredoc syntax may be better in your situation, given the variety of text you may want to write to a file.

Comment: Those spaces will cause `session_start` to error out because headers are already sent.

Comment: I just ran it on my localhost and it was fine.

Comment: No, I didn't mean this code, I meant the resulting index.php. That will break because of the spaces before the opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: That I don't know about. I didn't actually test the resulting script. I simply gave the OP what he asked for (and his sample code has spaces at the beginning).